# laravel-uploading laravel project in 000webhost

Tags: laravel

[image]

I've uploaded my project successfully and my login page appears.  However, when I try to login an error occurs.  I cannot understand what to do. In my local server it works perfectly.

Comment: You need to setup your mySQL database.  Look at the .env file, migrate or import your database.

Comment: assumed you have set things up as discussed [here](https://laravel.io/forum/03-06-2015-how-to-setup-laravel-5-in-shared-hosting), limit is right. you will need to set `.env` credentials, url, and setup the database (including the tables of course, using sql -- as on most shared hosting you can't run php artisan command).

Answer (score 0):

Your have to do just rename your "server.php" file to "index.php" on root